# Comparing multiple dates associated with one person

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to python, and I have a problem that I just can't work out. I have a dataset of thousands of people, each with a unique ID. Each person has up to thousands of rows of health data - diagnoses and then various billing entries, etc. A subset of these people have to be excluded from my analysis if they had Health Condition 1 and Health Condition 2 on the same day (In the example below, Person A has both Condition 1 and Condition 2 on the same day, and so they would be excluded from the analysis for that entry). How do I set this up? Another level is that I would prefer to create a sort of date buffer to exclude all dates within the same year of Condition 2 associated with each person in this subset. Thank you for any advice you might have!

| Person | Health Condition | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Condition 1 | Date 1 |
| Person A | Condition 1 | Date 2 |
| Person A | Condition 2 | Date 1 |
| Person A | Condition 1 | Date 3 |
| Person A | Condition 1 | Date 4 |

I've tried melting and unstacking, but it's been sort of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Person A', 'Person A', 'Person A', 'Person A', 'Person A'], 'Health Condition': ['Condition 1', 'Condition 1', 'Condition 2', 'Condition 1', 'Condition 1'], 'Date': ['2022-01-01 00:00:00','2022-08-01 00:00:00','2022-01-01 00:00:00','2022-03-03 00:00:00', '2022-04-04 00:00:00'], 'check': [True, False, True, False, False]})# df.columns=['Person','Health_Condition'   'Date']
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

'''
    Person Health Condition       Date
0  Person A       Condition 1 2022-01-01
1  Person A       Condition 1 2022-08-01
2  Person A       Condition 2 2022-01-01
3  Person A       Condition 1 2022-03-03
4  Person A       Condition 1 2022-04-04

'''
```

Then group by person and day and put the health condition into a list. If the list length is greater than 1 and values is different, we will have to drop it.

```
df['check']=df.groupby([df['Person'],df['Date'].dt.date])['Health Condition'].transform(lambda x: True if len(x) > 1 and np.unique(x).size == len(x) else False)
print(df)
'''
     Person Health Condition       Date  check
0  Person A      Condition 1 2022-01-01   True
1  Person A      Condition 1 2022-08-01  False
2  Person A      Condition 2 2022-01-01   True
3  Person A      Condition 1 2022-03-03  False
4  Person A      Condition 1 2022-04-04  False
'''
```

Now drop True values:

```
df=df[df['check'] != True] #or df=df[~df['check']]

'''
    Person  Health Condition    Date    check
1   Person A    Condition 1 2022-08-01  False
3   Person A    Condition 1 2022-03-03  False
4   Person A    Condition 1 2022-04-04  False

'''
```